# RegEx issue - Double matching numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm trying to swap out certain symbols in data with icons.

My current RegEx is `/\{.+?\}|\+\d+|\−\d+|\{[T]}|X|(0:)*/`
This actually hits every sample I have.

**Some Samples**

```
+2 −2 {2}
```

etc etc

However, it's also matching `+2/+2` and replacing each `+2` with the symbol for 
`+2`.

Now in each of my examples I use +2, but it can be any number from 1-100 (Mostly 1-10).
I'll post the `Rails Helper` I use to swap it. I tried about ~20 different versions of `[\+(0-9\/\+0-9)]` including one that txt2re suggested - `([-+]\\d+\/[-+]\\d+)` but I either A) Lost the effect that was working B) did nothing.

I welcome any suggestions. Will post 3 exact text samples for some of my issue having perspectives.

**Examples**

```
`+1: Tap target permanent. It doesn't untap during its controller's next untap step. −2: Draw a card for each tapped creature target player controls. −8: You get an emblem with "You have no maximum hand size" and "Whenever a card is put into your graveyard from anywhere, you may return it to your hand."`
```

The +1, −8 should become an icon (Also that isn't a normal - sign, but wider. Unsure it's technical name. Something to look into.

```
Equipped creature gets +1/+1 for each color among permanents you control. As long as Conqueror's Flail is attached to a creature, your opponents can't cast spells during your turn. Equip {2}
```

The +1/+1 is a variant number, but will almost always be in this format. However, sometimes it may be `*/+1` or `+1/*` - Unsure how to solve for this.

```
+2: Look at the top card of target player's library. You may put that card on the bottom of that player's library. 
0: Draw three cards, then put two cards from your hand on top of your library in any order. −1: Return target creature to its owner's hand. −12: Exile all cards from target player's library, then that player shuffles his or her hand into his or her library.
```

This is majority of the samples of the issue.

**My Helper**

```
  def card_text_swap card
    if card.nil?
      return
    else
    pos_entries = (1..20).map do |i|
      ["+#{i}", "<br /><i class=\"ms ms-loyalty-up ms-loyalty-#{i}\"></i>"]
    end.to_h
    neg_entries = (1..20).map do |i|
      ["−#{i}", "<br /><i class=\"ms ms-loyalty-down ms-loyalty-#{i}\"></i>"]
    end.to_h
    power_tough = (1..20).map do |i|
      ["+#{i}/", "<span></span>"]
    end.to_h
    cost_entries = (1..20).map do |i|
      ["{#{i}}", "<i class=\"ms ms-#{i} ms-cost ms-shadow\"></i>"]
    end.to_h
    hash = {    '{hw}' => '<span class="ms-half"><i class="ms ms-w ms-cost"></i></span>', 
                '{W}' => '<i class="ms ms-w ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>', 
                '{R}' => '<i class="ms ms-r ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{U}' => '<i class="ms ms-u ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{G}' => '<i class="ms ms-g ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{B}' => '<i class="ms ms-b ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{S}' => '<i class="ms ms-s ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{X}' => '<i class="ms ms-x ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                'X' => '<i class="ms ms-x ms-cost ms-shadow"></i>',
                '{W/U}' => '<i class="ms ms-wu ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{W/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-wb ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{W/P}' => '<i class="ms ms-wp ms-cost ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-2w ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{U/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-ub ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{U/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-ur ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{U/P}' => '<i class="ms ms-up ms-cost ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/U}' => '<i class="ms ms-2u ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{B/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-br ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{B/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-bg ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{B/P}' => '<i class="ms ms-bp ms-cost ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-2b ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{R/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-rg ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{R/P}' => '<i class="ms ms-rp ms-cost ms-cost"></i>',
                '{R/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-rw ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/R}' => '<i class="ms ms-2r ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{G/W}' => '<i class="ms ms-gw ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{G/B}' => '<i class="ms ms-gb ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '{G/P}' => '<i class="ms ms-gp ms-cost ms-cost"></i>',
                '{2/G}' => '<i class="ms ms-2g ms-split ms-cost"></i>',
                '0:' => '<br /><i class="ms ms-loyalty-zero ms-loyalty-0"></i>',
                '{T}' => '<i class="ms ms-tap"></i>',
                '{P}' => '<i class="ms ms-tap"></i>',
                '{C}' => '<i class="ms ms-c"></i>',
                '\n' => '<br>'
                }
    cost_entries = cost_entries.merge(neg_entries)
    cost_entries = cost_entries.merge(pos_entries)
    cost_entries = cost_entries.merge(power_tough)
    hash = hash.merge(cost_entries)
    card.gsub(/\{.+?\}|\+\d+|\−\d+|\{[T]}|X|(0:)*|(\+[0-9]\/)/) { | k | hash[k] || k }.html_safe
    end
  end
```

While being Rails specific, it's just generating hashes for me, that I then gsub out.

Comment: Without an MCVE, it is difficult to understand what you need. Try `/[-+]\d+\/[-+]\d+|\{.+?\}|\+\d+|\−\d+|\{[T]}|X|(0:)*/`. However, I do not get why you have `(0:)*` that matches any empty location before a non-matching symbol.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What do you mean? I provided 3 examples - One of those fails every time I try a different variant.

Your solution actually seems to work. Will you put it as an Answer with an explaination and I'll check some other cards and mark it as the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I see the issue now, I posted the answer with the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you tried adding the pattern to match 2 slash-separated numbers at the end of the regex, while you need to do it at *its start* because the order of alternatives in a non-anchored pattern matters:

```
/[-+]\d+\/[-+]\d+|\{.+?\}|\+\d+|-\d+|\{T\}|X|(0:)*/
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/h9q49rj3Iz)

Also, note that the `-` outside the character class does not have to be escaped.

And FYI: the `\{.+?\}` matches strings even like `{zzz{yyy{xxx}`. If you ever need to avoid that, use `\{[^{}]+\}`.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure how the ordering of RegEx mattered. Was another factor I was struggling with. I will keep spot checking cards and seeing if `\{.+?\}` is problematic.

Comment: You can read more about [alternations at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), *Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager* section.